# Numpy array of strings into an array of integers

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have the following array:

```
pattern = array([['[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]'],
       ['[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]'],
       ['[0, 1, 1, 1, 0]'],
       ['[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]'],
       ['[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]'],
       ['[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]'],
       ['[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]'],
       ['[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]'],
       ['[0, 1, 0, 1, 1]'],
       ['[0, 0, 1, 1, 0]'],
       ['[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]'],
       ['[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]']], dtype='<U15')
```

and I want to get it in non-string format as the following:

```
import numpy
my_array = numpy.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
                        ])
```

Any idea on how to do it non-manually?

Comment: Sure, list comprehension makes tasks like this pretty trivial, but what have you tried yourself already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy string operations to strip brackets (`[]`), splitting on comma and recast into an array with `int` dtype is possible:

```py
np.array(np.char.split(np.char.strip(pattern[:, 0], '[]'), ', ').tolist(), 'int')
```

but a list comprehension where you do the same things using python string methods is much easier to read (and faster as well) imo.

```py
np.array([row[0][1:-1].split(', ') for row in pattern], dtype='int')


# array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```